# Remove ^M character from log files

Tags: shell, command-line, newlines

Remove ^M character from log files.

In my script I redirect output of my program to a log file. The output of my log file contains some ^M (newline) characters. I need to remove them while running itself.

My command:

```
$ java -jar test.jar >> test.log
```

`test.log` has:

> Starting script ... ^M Starting script ...Initializing

Comment: Backspace is `^H`.

Comment: And ^M is carriage return (CR) which, on most terminals, returns to the first column of the current line - so like a soft backspace over the length of the line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Converting a standalone file

If you run the following command:

```
$ dos2unix <file>
```

The `<file>` will have all the ^M characters stripped. If you want to leave `<file>` intact, then simply run `dos2unix` like this:

```
$ dos2unix -n <file> <newfile>
```

#### Parsing output from a command

If you need to do them as part of a chain of commands via a pipe, you can use any number of tools such as `tr`, `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` to do this.

*tr*

```
$ java -jar test.jar | tr -d '^M' >> test.log
```

*sed*

```
$ java -jar test.jar | sed 's/^M//g' >> test.log
```

*awk*

```
$ java -jar test.jar | awk 'sub(/^M/,"")' >> test.log
```

*perl*

```
$ java -jar test.jar | perl -p -e 's/^M//g' >> test.log
```

#### Typing ^M

When entering the `^M` be sure to enter it in one of the following ways:

1. As <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and not <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.
2. As a backslash r, i.e. (`\r`).
3. As an octal number (`\015`).
4. As a hexidecimal number (`\x0D`).

#### Why is this necessary?

The `^M` is part of how end of lines are terminated on the Windows platform.  Each end of line is terminated with a carriage return character followed by a linefeed character.

On Unix systems the end of line is terminated by just a linefeed character.

- linefeed character = `0x0A` in hex, also written as `\n`.
- carriage return character = `0x0D` in hex, also written as `\r`.

#### Examples

You can see these if you pipe the output to a tool such as `od` or `hexdump`. Here's a sample file with the line terminating carriage returns + linefeed characters.

```
$ cat sample.txt
hi there
bye there
```

You can see them with `hexdump` as `\r` + `\n`:

```
$ hexdump -c sample.txt 
0000000   h   i       t   h   e   r   e  \r  \n   b   y   e       t   h
0000010   e   r   e  \r  \n                                            
0000015
```

Or as their hexidecimal `0d` + `0a`:

```
$ hexdump -C sample.txt 
00000000  68 69 20 74 68 65 72 65  0d 0a 62 79 65 20 74 68  |hi there..bye th|
00000010  65 72 65 0d 0a                                    |ere..|
00000015
```

Running this through `sed 's/\r//g'`:

```
$ sed 's/\r//g' sample.txt |hexdump -C
00000000  68 69 20 74 68 65 72 65  0a 62 79 65 20 74 68 65  |hi there.bye the|
00000010  72 65 0a                                          |re.|
00000013
```

You can see that `sed` has removed the `0d` character.

#### Viewing files with ^M without converting?

Yes you can use `vim` to do this. You can either set the `fileformat` setting in vim, which will have the effect of converting the file like we were doing above, or you can change the fileformat in the `vim` view.

*changing a file's format*

```
:set fileformat=dos
:set fileformat=unix
```

You can use the shorthand notation too:

```
:set ff=dos
:set ff=unix
```

Alternatively you can just change the fileformat of the view. This approach is nondestructive:

```
:e ++ff=dos
:e ++ff=unix
```

Here you can see me opening our `^M` file, `sample.txt` in `vim`:

[image: ss of vim dos #1]

Now I'm converting the fileformat in the view:

[image: ss of vim dos #2]

Here's what it looks like when converted to the `unix` fileformat:

[image: ss of vim dos #3]

#### References

- [Different ways to delete ^M character in a file](http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-delete-m-character-in.html)
- [Wikipedia Newline article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Thanks... I need to do an extra step after my command (java -jar test.jar >> test.log ) is it possible to ignore (^M) character while redirecting output itself ... ??

Comment: I used java -jar test.jar | sed 's/\r//g' >> test.log --- working great

Comment: @Ram - glad it solved your problem.

Comment: @sim The user tries to see the log file using vi test.log and cat -v test.log .. They are treating it as error so i am trying to hide that char .

Comment: @sim User is using only vi editor . They are not ready to set any settings in editor. They want code itself to handle it .

Comment: @Ram - understood, just letting you know, I've added how to the answer if you or they are curious.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10380/discussion-between-ram-and-slm)

Comment: This does NOT answer the question because the OP does not have a file with DOS line endings.  He has terminal output that uses the ^M to go back and modify the previous output on the line.

Comment: @psusi - did you even read this entire Q&A thread? I've talked with the OP and he's marked this as the accepted answer b/c it DOES fix his issue. He's redirecting the terminal output to a file that others are then viewing in `vi`. Please don't post comments on things you haven't read!

Comment: He said that sed worked, not dos2unix.  dos2unix looks for CR + NL and replaces them with just NL.  He doesn't have CR + NL.  Using sed to remove the CR also leaves you with both the before and after text concatenated on one line, so it won't look right compared to what you see on a terminal.

Comment: @psusi - He never said that dos2unix didn't work. He wanted a solution that would convert the CR by removing them from the log file as they wre being written. Other sections to my answer provide methods for doing this use `sed`, `tr`, etc. If you strip the CR from the file and then later more the resulting file it will look just fine, it still has the NL's. His output has CR + NL's. I believe you're misunderstanding what the OP's Q is.

Comment: The OP does not have a CR+NL, he has a CR followed by more text.  `dos2unix` won't remove such a CR because it isn't immediately followed by a NL.

Answer (score 2):

Shove the file through `dos2unix` to fix the line endings.

Or, use one of these:

```
sed 's,\r$,,'
tr -d '\r'
```

Comment: Thanks ...   
I used java -jar test.jar | sed 's/\r//g' >> test.log --- working great

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your program to call `isatty()` and if stdout is not a tty, then do not output the ^M.

Comment: This is your answer? Please re-read the question. The title even says "remove ... from log files".

Comment: @slm, yes... they shouldn't be in the log file in the first place.  Well written programs check that they are actually using a terminal before spitting out terminal control codes.

Comment: Let's not debate "well written" programs. Sometimes people don't have access to the software that they support and have to do things like this to get the job done. Perhaps instead of this answer, you could explain how one would do this from Java instead. Seems like a gap on this Q&A that you could direct your energies to rather than coming in, downvoting the accepted answer, and saying that it DOESN'T work when clearly it DOES.

Comment: Also in larger environments I've worked I've seen exactly this type of issue come up. It would be too  costly to go back and "fix" a program that is doing this, rather it's more cost effect to do something like this. I'd bet money that this software was developed on a PC and is now deployed on a Unix box, and the original developers would be the ones that don't understand testing the type of stdout, and then adjusting accordingly.

Comment: @psusi Thank you. In java code how to detect whether terminal or not ???

Answer (score 0):

Removal of ^M without special signs:

```
$ tr -d '\015' <file1 >file2 

$ mv file2 file1
```