# A grep code is not yielding the results it used to yield before

Tags: grep, regular-expression

A small `grep` code I used to use very often is not working as before. Bellow there is an example in which I have a data set with 7 rows and 3 columns, the dataset is named animal.txt:

```
Animal Habitat Family
Bear   forest  Ursidae
Dog    house   Canidae
Cat    house   Fenidae
Wolf   mountain Canidae
Eagle  mountain Accipitridae
Lion   sabana  Fenidae
```

I have a list with the names of 3 animals. What I want is to extract the lines that contains those names of animals. The list is named animal3.txt.

```
Dog
Cat
Bear
```

Both the dataset and the list are tab delimited files. The code I am using is:

```
grep -w -F -f ./animal3.txt ./animal.txt > ./output.txt
```

The output only have the line of `Bear` I have searched in several forums and haven't find something similar. I really don't know what is going on or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me. However, I'm assuming `animal.hmp.txt` is a typo, since you earlier stated the filename was `animal.txt`? Also, all three `./` are unnecessary. This means the file in the current directory, which is already implicit.

Comment: The first thing I would check for is non-printing characters in the file(s) -
 in particular, DOS line endings - e.g. `cat -et animal3.txt`

Comment: Is it possible that your file animal3.txt does not have the style of line ending it used to have, ie now it's CRLF?

Comment: Yes, I already checked it that and all the animal's names have those ^M$ terminators except the last one. So, It is very probably that is the reason grep is not working well. I did't know that. So, how can I remove that?

Comment: You can use any of the methods described here: [Remove ^M character from log files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/remove-m-character-from-log-files)

Comment: Thank you guys!. Yours comment were very useful. I already solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

From comments I gather that the `animal3.txt` file has carriage returns at the end of at least some lines. These characters becomes part of the pattern that `grep` is using which in turn makes the patterns not match in the `animal.txt` file.

If the file is not supposed to have any carriage returns, then you may use

```
tr -d '\r' <animal3.txt >animal3-new.txt
```

to delete them. You may then replace the original `animal3.txt` file with the corrected `animal3-new.txt` file.

Comment: The OP mentions the last line has no ^M which would indicate it's a MS-DOS type file also missing the last line delimiter. dos2unix would fix all those problems. Those types of files could also have UTF-8 BOMs or other idiosyncrasies.